# $n$ such that decimal digits of $2^n$ begins with $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are there infinitely many $n$ such that the decimal expansion $2^n$ begins with $n$?

For example, $2^6=64$ and $2^{10} =1024$.

It can easily be shown that this problem is equivalent to the following.

Are there infinitely many $n$ such that 
$\{n\log_{10}2-\log_{10}n\}<\log_{10}{(1+\frac{1}{n})}$?

Here, $\{x\}=x-[x]$, where [x] denotes the largest integral number that is smaller than $x$.

More generally, for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma > 0$,   are there infinitely many $n$ such that 
$\{\alpha n - \beta \log n\}<\frac{\gamma}{n}$?

I think it would help if I know something about the distribution of $\{\log n\}$.

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998744/n-such-that-decimal-digits-of-2n-begins-with-n – PLEASE DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: So this is a version of the *shrinking target* problem for the dynamical system $x\mapsto x+\log_{10}2\bmod 1$ (see http://www.math.umd.edu/~dolgop/TorusRev15.pdf for some known results - but which does not answer the current question). In this case, the targets are the sets $[\log_{10}n,\log_{10}(n+1))\bmod 1$.

Comment: As noted at the Math.SE post (thanks for pointing to it, Gerry), there is relevant material at OEIS: http://oeis.org/A100129

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general information on the problem, which is probably open.

As pointed out by Ivan Neretin at math.stackexchange, this is [OEIS A100129](http://oeis.org/A100129). There you can find the first 16 numbers with this property.

According to this paper,

- Jan van de Lune, "[A note on a problem of Erdős](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/7417/7417A.pdf)" (1978)

the problem goes back to Erdős:

> "Recently my attention was drawn to the following observation made by
>   P. Erdős: $2^6=64$ and $2^{10}=1024$. Here we have two examples of the
>   phenomenon that the number $2^n$ starts with the same ordered sequence
>   of digits as the natural number $n$ itself."

The characterization used in van de Lune's calculations is

$$0\leq \{n\log 2\}-\{\log n\}<\log(n+1)-\log n$$